# Access-Control-Allow-Origin (Laravel & Vue) CORS CORB error on localhost

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, cors

I use this package and it didn't work (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

[image]

```
addSMS() {
    axios.post('https://smsmisr.com/api/webapi', {
                headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, Accept, Content-Type',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    },
                username: '*****',
                passowrd: '****',
                etc: '',
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
```

please tell me how to fix it it's cors not working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have no access in API's source code so there is nothing to do with `.htaccess` or adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',` in script. But still you can eradicate this error by opening chrome browser with disabled security mode

In windows run CMD (press together windows button and `R` key from keyboard. Then type `cmd` in box and enter).

Secondly go to `C` drive (in CLI) or where your chrome installed (using `cd` command) then run following command

```
“Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe” –-allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --user-data-dir --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating
```

It will open your browser in disabled web security mode. Once you done it you can test now with this kind of `CORS` or `CORB` error.

note: before running this command make sure there are no chrome are opened already.

*`Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` this should be your chrome installed path*

However after opening browser it will show as below, dont panic & dont close this message. if you close this message it will again through this `CORS` or `CORB` error
[image]

Comment: I will try it but maybe it will not solve my problem this api work on postman as well

Comment: @AhmedMamdouh yes it will work postman even at live srrver when you add https. But this solution for localhost & development server

Comment: you mean when i upload my server it will work fine ?

Comment: it's working fine thank you, but i have question when i see in youtube all use localhost and it working with cors easy why i get this problem.

Comment: @AhmedMamdouh Perhaps in earlier version of chrome it works but there are a security issue & latest version dont allow to do that

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

to the following will solve the problem:

```
'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
```

Answer (score -1):

Update config/cors.php

```
   'supportsCredentials' => false,
   'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
   'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
   'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
   'exposedHeaders' => ['*'],
   'maxAge' => 0,

   then run
   php artisan config:cache 
   command i think it will help you
```

Comment: I do it and nothing