# Axios request receiving a CORS error only when inside a callback/async function

Tags: javascript, go, vue.js, cors, axios

I'm using VueJS for an app I am building. The server I have is written in Golang and has been set to accept CORS. In the app, in one of my components, `searchBar`, I have set it to fetch some data before it is created.

```
var searchBar = {
    prop: [...],
    data: function() {
        return { ... };
    },
    beforeCreate: function() {
        var searchBar = this;

        axios.request({
            url: '/graphql',
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'query': '{courses{id, name}}'
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            searchBar.courses = response.data.data.courses;
        });
    },
    methods: { ... },
    template: `...`
};
```

Axios works perfectly here. It gets the data I need. `searchBar` has a button which causes it to emit an event which is then picked up by another component, `searchResults`. Upon receiving the event, `searchResults` will fetch some data.

```
var searchResults = {
    data: function() {
        return { ... }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        var sr = this;

        this.$bus.$on('poll-server', function(payload) {
            var requestData = {
                url: '/graphql',
                method: 'post',
                data: { ... },
                ...
            };
            ...

            axios.request(requestData)
                 .then(function(response) {
                     console.log(response);
                 }
            );
        });
    },
    template: `...`
};
```

Note that my Axios request call is now inside a callback function. When this call is performed, I receive a CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/graphql' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My server is located at `http://127.0.0.1:9000`, with the client in `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. Here is the content of the `OPTIONS` request of the second request call.

[image: Second call's OPTIONS method request headers.]

For comparison, here is the request header of the first request call (that works!).

[image: First call's OPTIONS method request headers.]

I have already set my Golang server to support CORS via `go-chi/cors`. This is how set it up.

```
router := chi.NewRouter()
...    
// Enable CORS.
cors := cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"},
    AllowedMethods:   []string{"POST", "OPTIONS"},
    AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-CSRF-Token"},
    ExposedHeaders:   []string{"Link"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    MaxAge:           300,
})

router.Use(
    render.SetContentType(render.ContentTypeJSON),
    middleware.Logger,
    middleware.DefaultCompress,
    middleware.StripSlashes,
    middleware.Recoverer,
    cors.Handler,
)

router.Post("/graphql", gqlServer.GraphQL())

return router, db
```

What is causing the error I am having and how can it be solved?

Comment: Not familiar with go-chi/cors, but are you sure CORS is set up correctly? You most likely have it correct for your first POST request, but not for the second GET request. The error clearly shows no Allowed Origin header on the 2nd API.

Comment: @colminator I accidentally left the details for the second request. The second request is also a `POST` request.

Comment: Please check the `OPTIONS` request that is being sent to the server and the response and, if you could, post them here

Comment: @BenYaakobi, I have added the `OPTIONS` request to the question.

Comment: Is this the only request that is sent to server? Could you attach the response too?

Comment: I concur with Ben - see if the browser is issuing an OPTIONS  method (r.Method=="OPTIONS") in your graphql route. Perhaps the browser has cached CORS data which does not match your current server configuration?

Comment: The response header for OPTIONS does not have an Origin. So it will not honor your request - as per the browser error listed.

Comment: @BenYaakobi, there are previous requests that are sent to the server, all `POST`s and `OPTION`s but they were by `searchBar` component. I have attached the additional details as well.

Comment: @colminator, that is something I find quite odd. The first request receives `"Access-Control-Allow-*" headers, but not the second one.

Comment: For local you can try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545554/access-control-allow-origin-laravel-vue-cors-corb-error-on-localhost

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, thanks, but I find it impractical if I disable security mode in Chrome. It feels like fixing the symptom and not the root cause.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais This will not happen in production & browsers disable it for security, this is mentioned in chrome spcification

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, why would browsers disable web security mode if it is for security?

Comment: Please update the question to include your CORS setup. That is clearly the source of the problem.

Comment: @colminator, there ya' go. I updated it.

Comment: Again not family which chi - but is the middleware handlers order correct? Try putting CORS first instead of last in the router list.

Comment: @colminator, the call from my `searchResults` component still fails, but the call from my `searchBar` component works.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais for local test no security required

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, yes, for local test no security is required. But, it is much preferable to match the dev/local with what would be in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This CORS error is expected. The CORS plugin you are using does request filtering for you. If you look at the list of allowed headers, you can see it's missing the header called `snb-user-gps-location` that you are trying to send in your axios call.

Either add that header to the allowed list, or don't send it from the front end.

Comment: Woah! I did not think that my custom header being missing was causing my problem. I have confirmed that this is indeed the fix. Thank you very much!

Comment: It also shows how important it is to post all code related to your problem, if I haven't looked at your first screenshot of the request, I would have never spotted that this was your error, as that screenshot is the only place where this header is mentioned

Answer (score 2):

I still suspect the go-chi CORS setup. I would suggest looking at setting up CORS by hand. It's not that difficult. This page will get a basic setup: https://flaviocopes.com/golang-enable-cors/

If that works with your nested API setup, we can then work backwards to determine the go-chi config issue.

---

**Update:**

I would also investigate the other middleware steps - commenting out all non-essential ones.

Middleware handlers normally inspect the `r *http.Request` or write headers to the `w http.ResponseWriter` and then the final handler will write to the response *body*. But throughout the middleware chain the following header/body write flow should look like one of these two flows:

**Success:**

```
w.Header().Set(...) // headers
w.Write(...) // body
```

Note the above flow will issue an implicit http status code write, to keep headers appearing *first* and body *second*:

```
w.Header().Set(...) // headers
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) // implicit success http status code
w.Write(...) // body
```

**Failure:**

In the event of reporting a runtime error, the flow should be:

```
w.Header().Set(...) // headers
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError) // some unrecoverable error 
w.Write(...) // optional body
```

---

The reason I bring this up, I've seen 3 types of bugs which mess up this flow:

- bad middleware handlers write headers after the body causing client confusion
- calling `http.Error` thinking that stops the API dead - instead of returning immediately after the `http.Error` *and* ensuring no subsequent middleware handlers are called
- write the same header twice. Rewriting headers in a subsequent handler will cause the client to see the last version (thus clobbering any previous versions)

So to fully trace things, I would `log.Println` all header/body writes for your API to ensure the above flow is correct and no intended values are being overwritten.

Comment: Double API? I must have confused you. I apologize. The requests are calling to the same single API.

Comment: I understood your code. Double in the sense you are calling it twice.

Comment: Oh. I see. I think double API setup is misleading. Anyhow, perhaps setting it manually is workable.

Comment: One final thought: In the handler of the (2nd) API call is there any possible http error reporting? If so, writing error codes out of order from header-writes can lead to headers (Origin in this case) from never being sent.

Comment: Apparently, it turns that my problem was due to my custom header not being included in the allowed headers. This was pointed out and solved by Ferrybig [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55459139/1116098). Nevertheless, thank you for you effort.